# JPA: Circumvent N+1 when using constructor expression in JPQL to wrap singular entity in DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, spatial

first things first, I know about the similar question at ([Prevent "n+1 selects" with JPA/Hibernate constructor expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782029/prevent-n1-selects-with-jpa-hibernate-constructor-expression)) but my case is different and that other question doesn't have any sufficient answer.

I noticed that when I do a *JPQL* query using *Hibernate* as my *JPA* provider and I try to wrap an entity in a *DTO* by using the constructor expression, *Hibernate* seems to only select the entity's ID which later on leads to N+1 queries to get the rest of the properties.

**Hibernate Version:** 5.4.21.Final

**The Query:**

```
select new com.example.DistanceResult(p, distance(:center, p.location)) from Place p where dwithin(:center, p.location, :radiusMeters) = true
```

**Query Log:**

```
select place1_.id as col_0_0_, st_distance(?, place0_.location) as col_1_0_ from places place0_ inner join places place1_ on (place0_.id=place1_.id) where st_dwithin(?, place0_.location, ?)=true
binding parameter [1] as [OTHER] - [POINT (10.90943 48.37102)]
binding parameter [2] as [OTHER] - [POINT (10.90943 48.37102)]
binding parameter [3] as [DOUBLE] - [2000.0]

select place0_.id as id1_0_0_, place0_.location as location2_0_0_, place0_.name as name3_0_0_ from places place0_ where place0_.id=?
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [3]

select place0_.id as id1_0_0_, place0_.location as location2_0_0_, place0_.name as name3_0_0_ from places place0_ where place0_.id=?
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [4]
```

As you can see I'm trying to do a "entities located around geo point" type of query using *hibernate-spatial* but I don't think this is related to the problem. How can I tell hibernate to select the whole entity and then wrap it into the *DTO*? I already tried doing a fetch self join but this didn't help.

**Java Classes:** (Lombok is used)

```java
@Value
public class DistanceResult {
    Place place;
    Double distanceMeters;
}
```

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLACES")
public class Place extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    public Place(String name, Point location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Point location;
}
```

`BaseEntity` is pretty much `AbstractPersistable` from *spring-data-jpa* sans the ID definition.

Comment: Your name and location fields do not have a `@Column` annotation, is that correct?

Comment: That is because the default naming for those fields matches with my db schema. I tried adding @Column and it doesn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found one solution, but not sure if that is the best way to do it. Instead of using the *constructor expression* in the *JPQL* I used a (hibernate specific) `ResultTransformer`.

**Code:**

```java
public List<DistanceResult> findInDistance(Point center, double radiusMeters) {
    String jpql = "select p, distance(:center, p.location) from Place p where dwithin(:center, p.location, :radiusMeters) = true";

    return (List<DistanceResult>) entityManager.createQuery(jpql)
            .setParameter("center", center)
            .setParameter("radiusMeters", radiusMeters)
            .unwrap(Query.class)
            .setResultTransformer(
                    (ListResultTransformer)
                            (tuple, aliases) -> new DistanceResult(
                                    (Place) tuple[0],
                                    ((Number) tuple[1]).doubleValue()
                            )
            ).getResultList();
}
```

*Beware:* `ListResultTransformer` is part of Vlad Mihalcea's *hibernate-types* library. (See also: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-resulttransformer/)

**Query Log:**

```
select place0_.id as col_0_0_, st_distance(?, place0_.location) as col_1_0_, place0_.id as id1_0_, place0_.location as location2_0_, place0_.name as name3_0_ from places place0_ where st_dwithin(?, place0_.location, ?)=true
binding parameter [1] as [OTHER] - [POINT (10.90943 48.37102)]
binding parameter [2] as [OTHER] - [POINT (10.90943 48.37102)]
binding parameter [3] as [DOUBLE] - [2000.0]
```

Comment: I will not mark my own answer as accepted for now. Hoping for some external input.